# C# MySql query not returning value

Tags: c#, mysql

Im trying to execute a simple select but it does not work properly, I've used the same method with another table and worked perfectly, the only difference is that the other method had just one parameters instead of 3.

Method:

```
public List<Quilometragem> SelectKM(string placa, string startDate, string endDate, string query)
{
    MySqlDataReader rdr = null;

        List<Quilometragem> result = new List<Quilometragem>();

        Connect();

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = m_conn;
            cmd.CommandText = query;


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@placa", placa);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", endDate);

            cmd.Prepare();

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (rdr.Read())//Enquanto existir dados no select
            {
                Quilometragem cc = new Quilometragem();

                cc.id = rdr["id"] == null ? 0 : Int32.Parse(rdr["id"].ToString());

                cc.placa    = rdr["Placa"] == null ? "" : rdr["Placa"].ToString();
                cc.kmtrab   = rdr["kmtrab"] == null ? 0 : Double.Parse(rdr["kmtrab"].ToString());
                cc.kmpos    = rdr["kmpos"] == null ? 0 : Double.Parse(rdr["kmpos"].ToString());

                cc.date = rdr["date"] == null ? DateTime.MinValue : DateTime.Parse(rdr["date"].ToString());

                result.Add(cc);
            }

            rdr.Close();
            Close();

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            rdr.Close();
            Close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Query:

```
public static string SELECT_KM = "SELECT placa, kmtrab, kmpos " +
                        "FROM serede_quilometragem " +
                        "WHERE placa='@placa' AND CAST(DATE AS DATE) BETWEEN '@startdate' AND '@enddate' " +
                        "GROUP BY placa; ";
```

This works on mysql workbench

Comment: `WHERE placa='@placa'` isn't doing what you expect it to. Likewise your other parameters, also in quotes. Look carefully. In future, please tell us what exactly *is* happening and what you expected to happen, rather than just saying something doesn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't  quote your parameters. They will be seen as literals then.

Use `@startDate` instead of `'@startDate'`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably shouldn't add quotations to `@params`. Thus the query should read:

```
public static string SELECT_KM = "SELECT placa, kmtrab, kmpos " +
                        "FROM serede_quilometragem " +
                        "WHERE placa=@placa AND CAST(DATE AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate " +
                        "GROUP BY placa; ";
```

If you use `'@param'`, it is interpreted as a literary string.